# When static library needs position independent code

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, static-linking, position-independent-code

There are 3 files a.c, b.c, main.c:

```
// a.c
int a() { return 123; }

// b.c
extern int a();
int b() { return a(); }

// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern int b();
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", b());
    return 0;
}
```

`a.c` is build as a static library `liba.a`.

`b.c` is build as a shared library `libb.so`.

`liba.a` is then linked with (i.e. included into) `libb.so`.

`main.c` is built as an executable, and dynamically linked to `libb.so`.

The Makefile looks like:

```
all:
    gcc -c -fPIC -o a.o a.c
    ar rcs liba.a a.o

    gcc -c -fPIC -o b.o b.c
    gcc -shared -o libb.so b.o liba.a

    gcc -o main -L. -lb
```

`b.o` is compiled with the position-independent code flag, because it becomes a shared library.
Is it necessary to also build `a.o` as position-independent code, because it will be included into a shared library? At least on the system I'm testing it on, it seems to work fine when the first -fPIC is removed.

Also, if `main.c` would be changed to also declare `extern int a()` and call it (assuming `libb.so` makes it visible), would it then be needed to compile `a.o` as position-independent code? (On my system this also works without the -fPIC for `a.o`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all code that goes into shared library has to be compiled with `-fPIC` regardless of whether it's in an object file or static library.

It works without `-fPIC` in your case because modern distros [enable `-fPIC` by default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PIE) for security reasons:

```
$ echo 'int x; int foo() { return x; }' | gcc -x c - -S -o- | grep rip
        movl    x(%rip), %eax
```

It's better to keep it explicit in your build scripts for clarity though.